# 'User' object has no attribute 'date_format'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

views.py

```
settings=Settings.objects.get(user=2)
    if user.date_format == '0':
        date=datetime.datetime.strptime('%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
    else:
            date=datetime.datetime.strptime('%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%m/%d/%Y')  
    if request.method == 'POST':            
        reportform = ReportForm(instance=report,data=request.POST)
        if reportform.is_valid():
            report = reportform.save(commit=False) 
            report.user = request.user
            report.save()
            return redirect('/member/media/')
```

models.py

```
class Settings(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    date_format = models.CharField('Date format', max_length=100)
    time_format = models.CharField('Time format', max_length=100)

class Report(models.Model):
    manual_date = models.DateField('Another date', null=True, blank=True)
    manual_time = models.TimeField('Another time', null=True, blank=True)
```

template is

```
 {{ form.manual_date }}{{ form.manual_date.errors }}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{ form.manual_time }}{{ form.manual_time.errors }}
                            </td>
```

To convert the date and time format in views, assumption is if date_format value is '0' the date should be of dd/mm/yy format,if value is '1' it gives the format of (mm/dd/yyyy).I know the error is in 2nd line in views.py, need help to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>     settings=Settings.objects.get(user=2)
>     if user.date_format == '0':
>         date=datetime.datetime.strptime('%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
>     else:
>             date=datetime.datetime.strptime('%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
> ```

You may want to use `settings.date_format` instead of `user.date_format`.

Comment: that worked,i have different field for date and time in models,to convert date  format and time format is that the correct method.Now i am getting this error "strptime() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)"